# Query to Fetch next record with order by clause

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

I am working on mysql. I am fetching list of records from a table and from that I am going to details of one of the record. Now I want to fetch the next record of that list.

I have below query

```
select * from table_name where column3 like %z% order by column2;
```

Result of that query

```
column1 | column2 | column3
10      | abc1    | zzzz
2       | abc2    | zsdazz
20      | abc3    | sddszz
```

I have selected record with column1 value 2. Now I want a query which can fetch next record, in this case record with column1 as 20.

Note: I have thousands of records in the table and user can select any record and then go to next record.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `where` clause and subquery:

```
select *
from table_name
where column3 like '%z%' and
      column2 > (select column2
                 from table_name
                 where column1 = 2 and column3 like '%z%'
                )
order by column2;
```

Note:  if `column1` is unique, then the `column3 like '%z%' is not necessary.

Comment: your query works fine if values in column2 are unique. How to handle non-unique valued column2.

Comment: If there are duplicates in `table_name`, then you can use `select max(column2)` in the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Use [**LIMIT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html) clause

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE column3 LIKE %z% 
ORDER BY column2 LIMIT 2, 1;
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how will I get that magic number `2`, which I can use in limit clause.

Comment: Your query is working, but suppose I have 10k records and how will get the record number which I am fetching i.e. row number which is included in limit clause.

Comment: I have accepted the answer given by @GordonLinoff. But still I would like to know how I can prepare that number which I can put in the limit clause.

Comment: What login in detail are you asking?

Comment: Suppose I am selecting record from the result with column1 value say 55, but in limit clause I will have to specify the row number of that record from the result list which I previously fetched. Using what query I can fetch that row number?

Comment: Sorry could not continue the chat on that day. Can you please provide your input whenever you are free. Thank you!